# Using a domain name without a subdomain causes routing to fail

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I'm trying to create a simple app using traefik to handling routing and SSL, but I'm running into issues when I want to use 'example.com' instead of 'subdomain.example.com'

If I try to include a service with a frontend rule of just 'example.com' the only rule that works is 'monitor.example.com'. 'api.example.com' won't work and returns a 404. If I comment out the frontend rule for 'example.com' then 'api.example.com' works again. But, no matter what, 'monitor.example.com' works fine. Additionally, 'example.com' always returns a 404 no matter what as well.

Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  reverse-proxy:
    image: traefik
    restart: always
    command: --docker
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - web
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:monitor.example.com"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.backend=traefik"
    environment:
      - CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL=###
      - CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY=###
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /home/project/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - /home/project/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json
    container_name: traefik

  api:
    image: api
    expose:
      - 5080
    restart: always
    networks:
      - web
    container_name: api
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:api.example.com"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.port=5080"
      - "traefik.backend=api"

  app:
    image: app
    restart: always
    networks:
      - web
    container_name: app
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:example.com"
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.docker.network=web"
      - "traefik.backend=app"
      - "traefik.port=80"

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

And here's my traefik configuration:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["https", "http"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]
  [entryPoints.trdash]
  address = ":8080"
    [entryPoints.trdash.auth]
      [entryPoints.trdash.auth.basic]
        users = [
          "admin:###",
        ]

[api]
entryPoint = "trdash"

[acme]
email = "###"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true
onDemand = false
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "example.com"
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "*.example.com"
[acme.dnsChallenge]
  provider = "cloudflare"
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:
Okay, I seem to have solved my own problem by disabling the 'orange cloud' on the domains I'm using on Cloudflare. Additionally I had to remove my http to https redirect rules inside of the traefik.toml file. I don't understand why this is a problem, so I'm going to leave the question open. This really seems to negate much of the value which Cloudflare provides.

Comment: Perhaps this is pertinent information: My cloudflare DNS is setup to put the monitor.example.com subdomain through Cloudflare while example.com and api.example.com are set to bypass cloudflare. Should this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the issue was enabling the Cloudflare proxy (orange cloud) without enabling the backend SSL. So long as I have SSL certs on the server (which I do via Let's Encrypt) I can turn Cloudflare SSL to 'Full (strict)' and it appears that the routing works fine now.

Thanks to Daniel Tomcej on the Traefik Slack for helping me find this answer.